# Why doesn´t my program send ARP requests (c++)?

Tags: c++, linux, arp, raw-sockets

I am learning low level sockets with c++. I have done a simple program that shall send an ARP request. The socket seems to send the packet but I cannot catch it with Wireshark. I have another small program that also sends ARP packets and those packets are captured by Wireshark (my program below is inspired by that program).

Have I done something wrong?

*Removed code*

**EDIT**

*Removed code*

**EDIT 2**
It seems that I also need to include ethernet header data in the packet, so I now make a packet containing ethernet header and ARP header data. Now the packet goes away and is captured by Wireshark. But Wireshark says it is gratuitous. As you can see, nor IP or MAC address of sender and receiver seem to have been set properly.

```
36  13.318179   Cimsys_33:44:55 Broadcast   ARP 42  Gratuitous ARP for <No address> (Request)
```

**EDIT 3**

```
    /*Fill arp header data*/
    p.arp.ea_hdr.ar_hrd = htons(ARPHRD_ETHER); 
    p.arp.ea_hdr.ar_pro = htons(ETH_P_IP); 
    p.arp.ea_hdr.ar_hln = ETH_ALEN;            // Must be pure INTEGER, not called with htons(), as I did
    p.arp.ea_hdr.ar_pln = 4;                   // Must be pure INTEGER, not called with htons(), as I did
    p.arp.ea_hdr.ar_op = htons(ETH_P_ARP);
```

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger (like `gdb`), or to use `strace`? Are you running your program with enough privileges?

Comment: I have not tried the debuggers (I am kind of new to c++). I will check it out. I am running the program as root.

Comment: Also, compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and improve your code till no warning is given. Notice that recent GCC compilers (e.g. version 4.7) are better (notably w.r.t. recent standards conformance, optimizations, warnings, ...) than older ones, particularly for C++

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thanks for the tip! I am now compiling with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`.

Comment: Solved it. Look at my edit 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user315052 say that you should use `memcpy(arp->arp_spa, &s_in_addr, sizeof(arg->arp_spa));` but this code just copy first 4 bytes of `s_in_addr` to `arp->arp_spa` that absolutely do nothing!
so just try this:

```
* (int32_t*) arp->arp_spa = inet_addr("192.168.1.1")
* (int32_t*) arp->arp_tpa = inet_addr("192.168.1.2")
```

Comment: I am novice in C programming, but what kind of casting is that when you put it before the `=` operator? I though you just could cast types/objects after the assignment, like `int i = (int)5.5;`

Comment: the actual type of `arp_spa/arp_tpa` is a 32 bit IP address of source/target that in C represented with `int32_t`. And name of each array( without any index [...] ) point to the address of array. So I first interpret address of array as address of `int32_t` using `(int*)` and then dereference that address using * operator. So all I say is take that 4 byte in `arp_spa/arp_tpa` interpret it as an `int32_t` and then copy result of `inet_addr("...")` into that address. In case that you get error from `int32_t` it is declared in `stdint.h` so add `#include <stdint.h>` to start of your file

Answer (score 3):

This code does not look quite right:

```
struct in_addr *s_in_addr = (in_addr*)malloc(sizeof(struct in_addr));
struct in_addr *t_in_addr = (in_addr*)malloc(sizeof(struct in_addr));

s_in_addr->s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.5");  // source ip
t_in_addr->s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.6");  // target ip

memcpy(arp->arp_spa, &s_in_addr, 6);
memcpy(arp->arp_tpa, &t_in_addr, 6);
```

In the `memcpy` You care copying 6 bytes out. However, you are taking an address of a pointer type, which makes it a pointer to a pointer type. I think you meant to just pass in `s_in_addr` and `t_in_addr`.

**Edit:** Alan Curry notes that you are copying 6 bytes from and to objects that are only 4 bytes long.

However, it doesn't seem like the dynamic allocation is doing your code any good, you should just create the the `s_in_addr` and `t_in_addr` variables off the stack. Than, you would not need to change your `memcpy` code.

```
struct in_addr s_in_addr;
struct in_addr t_in_addr;

s_in_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.5");  // source ip
t_in_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.6");  // target ip

memcpy(arp->arp_spa, &s_in_addr, sizeof(arg->arp_spa));
memcpy(arp->arp_tpa, &t_in_addr, sizeof(arg->arg_tpa));
```

There is a similar problem with your `arp` packet itself. So you should allocate it off the stack. To prevent myself from making a lot of code changes, I'll illustrate it slightly differently:

```
struct ether_arp arp_packet;
struct ether_arp *arp = &arp_packet;
//...
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (sendto(sock, arp, sizeof(arp_packet), 0,
               (struct sockaddr *)&sending_socket,
               sizeof(sending_socket)) < 0) { 
        std::cout << "Could not send!" << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I made some small changes according to your answer (look at my edit), but it still doesn´t work. Wireshark does not capture the ARP messages, but the program compiles fine and does run and the `sendto()` function seems to work since it is not printing "Could not sent!". Any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the message is going though a different interface than the one you believe it should be going through?

Comment: Yes, I am using the right interface. Do I need to use an ethernet header in the socket or something?

Comment: @Rox: You can try using `memset` to zero out your structures first before filling them in, as the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw) says it behaves differently if some fields are zeroed out.

Comment: Now we are a step closer. :-) I tested to include the ethernet header in the packet (along with the ARP header). Check my second edit in my post above. Now the packet is captured by Wireshark, but it is almost empty. No IP och MAC address seem to have been set properly since it is missing in the packet (at least Wireshark cannot display the sender/target IP and MAC address).

Comment: IP addresses are 4 bytes, not 6. memcpying 6 bytes into a 4 byte field is not good

Comment: Copying first 4 bytes of in_addr into a memory is not a good idea, any structure must used as a whole! You can't use just part of an structure unless that part is another type or structure that contain standalone meaning. so `memcpy(arp->arp_spa, &s_in_addr, sizeof(arg->arp_spa))` absolutely do nothing since you are reading first 4 bytes of `in_addr` that mean nothing

Comment: @BigBoss: I don't understand what you are objecting to. However, you should not copy data from one structure to another unless the types of source and target have the same size and semantic intent anyway. So, casting for assignment is no safer that memcpy (and mempcy is safer in my opinion as well).

Comment: You are just right, I was just sleepy and I just thought the type of structure is `sockaddr_in` not `in_addr`, appologize for that :). but fist `memcpy` does not generate same code with cast( you can compile and see ) and beside that `in_addr` is an opaque structure that may contain additional fields added by OS but `int_addr(...)` should always return an IP witch is 32 bit. again sorry for invalid objection